# Print text in html textarea tag

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a page that collects data from a database then prints it into another form so the user can update it.

It works with the input box, but not the textarea box.

Here is the code in the form:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" value="<?php echo $row['description'];?>">
</textarea>
```

I'm pretty sure the rest of my code works fine, can anyone see whats wrong with this?

Comment: There is no `value` attribute with textareas, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea.

Comment: LOL! So simple! ahh feel so stupid now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) doesn't have a value attribute. You have to put your echo statement in between the tags like this:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description">
<?php echo $row['description'];?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Code should be like this:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description"><?php echo $row['description'];?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea id="description" name="description"><?php echo $row['description'];?>
</textarea>
```